# jQuery code not working on Browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am facing a problem that: I have some JQuery code in my HTML View that works fine on my Google Chrome Browser but on another machine(server) Google Chrome the same code if Published on iiS, jQuery stops working.

jS is enabled in Browser but why is this jQuery code not being picked ? Please advise.

**Error in SOURCE HTML while ALL JS/jQuery files arre added in path:** 
[image]

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Show";
 }
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

@*<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5">*@

<title>Wallboard B</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/cssNew/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/cssNew/style.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


</head>
```

```
<span id="View1">

<section class="gage-wrap">
    <div class="container-fluid stretch">
        <div class="row no-gutter">

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="row no-gutter">

                    <!----- Avg Handle Meter ------>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 gage">
                        <h1>Avg Handle Time (Sec)</h1>
                        <canvas id="avg_handle_meter" width="285" height="170">
                            Canvas not available.
                        </canvas>
                        <span id="avg_handle_value">@ViewBag.averageHandleTime</span> <!---Print Speed -->

                    </div>

                    <!----- Avg Handle Meter End ------>
                    <!----- Avg Speed Meter ------>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 gage">
                        <h1>Avg Speed of Answer (Sec)</h1>
                        <canvas id="avg_speed_meter" width="285" height="170">
                            Canvas not available.
                        </canvas>
                        <span id="avg_speed_value">@ViewBag.averageSpeedOfAnswer</span> <!---Print Speed -->
                    </div>

                    <!----- Avg Speed Meter End ------>

                </div>
            </div><!--/col-md-3-->

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row no-gutter">

                    <!----- Service Level Meter ------>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 gage">
                        <h1>Service Level %</h1>
                        <canvas id="service_level_meter" width="580" height="333">
                            Canvas not available.

                        </canvas>

                        <span id="service_level_value">@ViewBag.serviceLevel</span><!---Print Speed -->
                    </div>


                    <!----- Service Level Meter End ------>


                    <div class="col-lg-12 gage time">
                        <h1>Longest Call in Queue</h1>

                        <span>@ViewBag.longestCallInQueue</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--/col-md-6-->
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="row no-gutter">

                    <!----- Total Calls Meter ------>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 gage">
                        <h1>Total Calls in Queue</h1>
                        <canvas id="total_calls_meter" width="285" height="170">
                            Canvas not available.
                        </canvas>
                        <span id="total_calls_value">@ViewBag.callsInQueue</span><!---Print Speed -->
                    </div>

                    <!----- Total Calls Meter End ------>
                    <!----- Abandoned Rate Meter ------>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 gage">
                        <h1>Abandoned Rate %</h1>
                        <canvas id="abandoned_rate_meter" width="285" height="170">
                            Canvas not available.
                        </canvas>
                        <span id="abandoned_rate_value">@ViewBag.abandRate</span><!---Print Speed -->
                    </div>

                    <!----- Abandoned Rate Meter End ------>


                </div>
            </div><!--/col-md-3-->

        </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/container-fluid-->
</section><!--/gage-wrap--><!--/gage-wrap-->

        <footer style="margin-top:8%">
            <p>Powered by Expertflow BI Services</p>
        </footer>



        @*<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>*@



</span>            


<span id="View2">
    <div id="div2">
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>High ARPU - H+HVC</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <section class="the-table">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row no-gutter row-eq-height">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Logged In Agents</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.loggedInAgents</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>On Calls</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.onCalls</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Agents In Ready</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.agentsInReadyState</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Agents In Not Ready</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.agentsInNotReadyState</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Agents In Wrapup</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.agentsInWrapup</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Reserved Agents</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.reservedAgents</span></span>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/row-->
                <div class="row no-gutter">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Calls Offered</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.callsOffered</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Calls Answered</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.callsAnswered</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Calls Abandoned</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.callsAbandoned</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Calls In Queue</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.callsInQueue</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Longest Talk Duration</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.longestTalkDuration</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        <em><span>Abandoned %</span></em>
                        <span><span>@ViewBag.AbandRate</span></span>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/row-->
            </div><!--/container-fluid-->
        </section><!--/the-table-->

        <section class="the-table wide">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row no-gutter">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <em class="large">Service Level %</em>
                        <span class="large">@ViewBag.serviceLevel</span>
                        <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                        <em>AHT (Sec)</em>
                        <span>@ViewBag.averageHandleTime</span>
                        <em>ASA (Sec)</em>
                        <span>@ViewBag.averageSpeedOfAnswer</span>
                        <em>Max Time In Queue</em>
                        <span>@ViewBag.longestCallInQueue</span>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/row-->
            </div><!--/container-fluid-->
        </section><!--/the-table-->

        <footer>
            <p>Powered by Expertflow BI Services</p>
        </footer>





    </div>
</span>
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/service-level-meter.js">   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/avg-handle-meter.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/total-calls-meter.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/avg-speed-meter.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/abandoned-rate-meter.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery-latest.min"></script>
  <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min"></script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {  

function ToggleFunction() {
    $('#View2').hide();

    alert("HELLO from VIEW1")
    myVar = setTimeout(SecondView, 11000);


}

function SecondView() {
    $('#View1').hide();
    alert("HELLO from VIEW2")
    $('#View2').show();
}

});
</script
```

Comment: does the console say anything?

Comment: You'll need to boil it down to a [mcve]. Remote debugging is not what Stack Overflow is set up for.

Comment: you should have jquery include before your other javascript includes as they often require jquery, like bootstrap

Comment: So start debugging. Your console screenshot shows you exactly what the errors are.

Comment: deppem@ Sir I have that path set in my Script Tag at the end of Code

Comment: You have bootstap.js higher in the DOM than jQuery.js bootstrap throws that error if jQuery isnt loaded prior to bootstrap initializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jquery.min.js put it above all your other js files.  Jquery library has to load before the rest  of the jquery plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery-latest.min"></script> <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="~/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> <script src="~/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min"></script>
```

Now load the the other js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/service-level-meter.js"> </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/avg-handle-meter.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/total-calls-meter.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/avg-speed-meter.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jsNew/abandoned-rate-meter.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```